# app phonegap frozen on start (black screen)

Tags: android, cordova

I have an android app that doesn't start only on my device (Htc one x).

It has always worked, but today no.

If I do :

```
adb logcat | grep mypersonalapp
```

this is the result:

```
I/DEBUG   (  141): pid: 7693, tid: 7693, name: rowd.mypersonalapp  >>> com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp <<<
I/ActivityManager(  511): Process com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp (pid 7693) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  511): Start proc com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp for activity com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp/.mypersonalapp: pid=7716 uid=10008 gids={50008, 3003, 5012, 1015, 1028}
F/libc    ( 7716): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7716 (rowd.mypersonalapp) - sent from sys
I/DEBUG   (  141): pid: 7716, tid: 7716, name: rowd.mypersonalapp  >>> com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp <<<
I/ActivityManager(  511): Process com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp (pid 7716) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  511): Start proc com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp for activity com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp/.mypersonalapp: pid=7734 uid=10008 gids={50008, 3003, 5012, 1015, 1028}
F/libc    ( 7734): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7734 (rowd.mypersonalapp) - sent from sys
I/DEBUG   (  141): pid: 7734, tid: 7734, name: rowd.mypersonalapp  >>> com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp <<<
I/ActivityManager(  511): Process com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp (pid 7734) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  511): Start proc com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp for activity com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp/.mypersonalapp: pid=7751 uid=10008 gids={50008, 3003, 5012, 1015, 1028}
F/libc    ( 7751): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7751 (rowd.mypersonalapp) - sent from sys
I/DEBUG   (  141): pid: 7751, tid: 7751, name: rowd.mypersonalapp  >>> com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp <<<
I/ActivityManager(  511): Process com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp (pid 7751) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  511): Start proc com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp for activity com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp/.mypersonalapp: pid=7774 uid=10008 gids={50008, 3003, 5012, 1015, 1028}
F/libc    ( 7774): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7774 (rowd.mypersonalapp) - sent from sys
I/DEBUG   (  141): pid: 7774, tid: 7774, name: rowd.mypersonalapp  >>> com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp <<<
I/ActivityManager(  511): Process com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp (pid 7774) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  511): Start proc com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp for activity com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp/.mypersonalapp: pid=7793 uid=10008 gids={50008, 3003, 5012, 1015, 1028}
F/libc    ( 7793): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7793 (rowd.mypersonalapp) - sent from sys
I/DEBUG   (  141): pid: 7793, tid: 7793, name: rowd.mypersonalapp  >>> com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp <<<
I/ActivityManager(  511): Process com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp (pid 7793) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  511): Start proc com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp for activity com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp/.mypersonalapp: pid=7814 uid=10008 gids={50008, 3003, 5012, 1015, 1028}
F/libc    ( 7814): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7814 (rowd.mypersonalapp) - sent from sys
I/DEBUG   (  141): pid: 7814, tid: 7814, name: rowd.mypersonalapp  >>> com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp <<<
I/ActivityManager(  511): Process com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp (pid 7814) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  511): Start proc com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp for activity com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp/.mypersonalapp: pid=7831 uid=10008 gids={50008, 3003, 5012, 1015, 1028}
F/libc    ( 7831): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7831 (rowd.mypersonalapp) - sent from sys
I/DEBUG   (  141): pid: 7831, tid: 7831, name: rowd.mypersonalapp  >>> com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp <<<
I/ActivityManager(  511): Process com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp (pid 7831) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  511): Start proc com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp for activity com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp/.mypersonalapp: pid=7848 uid=10008 gids={50008, 3003, 5012, 1015, 1028}
F/libc    ( 7848): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7848 (rowd.mypersonalapp) - sent from sys
I/DEBUG   (  141): pid: 7848, tid: 7848, name: rowd.mypersonalapp  >>> com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp <<<
I/ActivityManager(  511): Process com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp (pid 7848) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  511): Start proc com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp for activity com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp/.mypersonalapp: pid=7871 uid=10008 gids={50008, 3003, 5012, 1015, 1028}
F/libc    ( 7871): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7871 (rowd.mypersonalapp) - sent from sys
I/DEBUG   (  141): pid: 7871, tid: 7871, name: rowd.mypersonalapp  >>> com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp <<<
I/ActivityManager(  511): Process com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp (pid 7871) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  511): Start proc com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp for activity com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp/.mypersonalapp: pid=7896 uid=10008 gids={50008, 3003, 5012, 1015, 1028}
F/libc    ( 7896): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7896 (rowd.mypersonalapp) - sent from sys
I/DEBUG   (  141): pid: 7896, tid: 7896, name: rowd.mypersonalapp  >>> com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp <<<
I/ActivityManager(  511): Process com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp (pid 7896) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  511): Start proc com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp for activity com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp/.mypersonalapp: pid=7913 uid=10008 gids={50008, 3003, 5012, 1015, 1028}
F/libc    ( 7913): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7913 (rowd.mypersonalapp) - sent from sys
I/DEBUG   (  141): pid: 7913, tid: 7913, name: rowd.mypersonalapp  >>> com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp <<<
I/ActivityManager(  511): Process com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp (pid 7913) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  511): Start proc com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp for activity com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp/.mypersonalapp: pid=7935 uid=10008 gids={50008, 3003, 5012, 1015, 1028}
F/libc    ( 7935): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7935 (rowd.mypersonalapp) - sent from sys
I/DEBUG   (  141): pid: 7935, tid: 7935, name: rowd.mypersonalapp  >>> com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp <<<
```

Seems that the process is killed and restarted continuously.

Any ideas?

Could be a phone problem?

UPDATE:

```
Process created for activity com.crowdmine.mypersonalapp/.MyPersonalApp
                           PID: 29030   UID: 10008   GIDs: {50008, 3003, 5012, 1015, 1028}

              dalvikvm  W  JNI WARNING: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal continuation byte 0x5f
                        W               string: 'en_Latn_US_�_IT'
                        W               in Llibcore/icu/ICU;.addLikelySubtags:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/St
                           ring; (NewStringUTF)
                        I  "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
                        I    | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40efba78 self=0x5711c010
                        I    | sysTid=29030 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074533852
                        I    | state=R schedstat=( 19753000 4908000 26 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=2
                        I    #00  pc 000012a0  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+27)
                        I    #01  pc 000672bc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget cons
                           t*, int)+35)
                        I    #02  pc 000592d8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*,
                            Thread*, bool)+335)
                        I    #03  pc 0005937a  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
                        I    #04  pc 0003a7e6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
                        I    #05  pc 0003c4c6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
                        I    #06  pc 0003e7fa  /system/lib/libdvm.so
                        I    #07  pc 00016412  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
                        I    #08  pc 00016828  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
                        I    #09  pc 0001e690  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
                        I    #10  pc 0005100e  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JVa
                           lue*, Method const*, Thread*)+425)
                        I    #11  pc 00027aa0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
                        I    #12  pc 0002ce84  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JVal
                           ue*)+232)
                        I    #13  pc 000674be  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, A
                           rrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+373)
                        I    #14  pc 0007066e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
                        I    #15  pc 00027aa0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
                        I    #16  pc 0002ce84  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JVal
                           ue*)+232)
                        I    #17  pc 000671a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Ob
                           ject*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+271)
                        I    #18  pc 0004d2d6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
                        I    #19  pc 0004d38e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
                        I    #20  pc 0004e22c  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::star
                           t(char const*, char const*)+539)
                        I    #21  pc 00000e66  /system/bin/app_process
                        I    #22  pc 000128b0  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+35)
                        I    at libcore.icu.ICU.addLikelySubtags(Native Method)
                        I    at android.text.TextUtils.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(TextUtils.java:1742)
                        I    at android.content.res.Configuration.setLayoutDirection(Configuration.java:1376)
                        I    at android.content.res.Configuration.updateFrom(Configuration.java:851)
                        I    at android.app.ActivityThread.applyConfigurationToResourcesLocked(ActivityThread.j
                           ava:4411)
                        I    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4863)
                        I    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:162)
                        I    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432)
                        I    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                        I    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                        I    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
                        I    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                        I    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                        I    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083
                           )
                        I    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
                        I    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                        E  VM aborting
                  libc  F  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 29030 (rowd.MyPersonalApp) - s
                           ent from sys

                           Process 29030 ended
```

Comment: If you look at the unfiltered logcat is there more information there that could help? Maybe filter by PID or package if you need to. There's little of use in what you posted.

Comment: I have already filtered by package name, by id is not possible because it change every time

Comment: That grep checks for the package name being used in the log message not the log entries generates by a package. The PID is printed on every log entry so it would be easy to get one. I'd guess that one iteration of the start, crash, restart loop is all you'd need to look into as each will be identical so just check one of the used PIDs

Comment: In which file should I check? let's try with 7848

Comment: When you've gotten one edit it into your question.

Comment: every log entry of which file? And how can I check with adb? @indivisible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54733/discussion-between-beddamadre-and-indivisible).